# Slimscroll is not working in IE7 with height100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, scrollbar

I am using slimscroll bar in my website but it is not working in IE7 with auto or 100% height. if i give it a fixed height then it will work.
But i need the 100% height ant it is working in all browsers except IE7.
I made this page in HTML5.

If i change the doctype to xhmtl then it works with height 100% and  *height:1040px (hack for IE7). But the problem is that i can not change the doctype because i am working in HTML5.

Please tell me if you have any idea.
http://daawatcaterings.com/try/
(check the scrollbar in body part on mouse over.)

I get the scrollbar code from here
http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IE7 does not support the newest (or even most of the old ones, really...) HTML5 standards. Are you absolutely sure you have to support such an old version?

Answer (score 0):

slimScroll only supports pixel-based values, so auto or % values are invalid and will not work.